# nginx redirect all requests to root unless it's root

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to redirect permanent all (except for exceptions) requests to the root / where it will serve the file whatever.html

.i.e.

```
All should give 301 permanent to /
http:://www.domain.tld/whatever/anything/realy  == 301 ==> http://www.domain.tld
http:://www.domain.tld/blabla  == 301 ==> http://www.domain.tld
http:://www.domain.tld/ == 301 ==> http://www.domain.tld

except for
http://www.domain.tld/special.html == serve ==> special.html


root should serve the defailt file (as specificed in index)
http:://www.domain.tld  == serve => somefile.html
```

any ideas?

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137072/redirect-all-requests-to-a-subdomain-except-the-root-url-and-index-page-under-ng